# Sharepoint2010 and SSRS issues

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I have deployed ssrs reports to sharepoint. When I browse the report first page is getting displayed but when i moved to next page i am getting below Error.

**Error 
      Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error. (rsSharePointError)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors**

Also in the Report Page 1 for exporting the reports data when i click the Actions menu (to list the dropdown items) for type of  export i am getting the error

**An Error Occured with the data fetch. Please refresh the page and try.**

Kindly let me know what cause this error. No application log was written in the sharepoint application. 
Or kindly let me know what is the debug steps to find the underlaying error to find the root cause.

I am using sharepoint 2010 and ssrs 2008R2

Comment: You can get more details by looking at the ssrs logs on the server C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<VERSION>\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: You might also try [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)